# How can I change the Right-Click menu of a RichTextBlock in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, menu, flyout, richtextblock

I want to override the right-click menu in a `RichTextBlock` or a `TextBlock`, I have been searching for the solution and tried using `RightTappedEvent`, but it did not fire when right tapped a chosen text, but it fired when I right tapped in elsewhere in the control.

[image: Right-click Menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ContextFlyout` to change it.

You can add the `ContextFlyout` to custom your menu.

The code shows how to add the custom menu.

```
    <RichTextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <RichTextBlock.ContextFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="1" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="2" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </RichTextBlock.ContextFlyout>
        <Paragraph>Welcome to my blog http://blog.lindexi.com I write some UWP blogs</Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
```

[image]

See [UWP How to custom RichTextBlock right click menu](https://blog.lindexi.com/post/uwp-how-to-custom-richtextblock-right-click-menu.html)

All code is in [github](https://github.com/lindexi/lindexi_gd/tree/7a716887868435aab72683997806c9e7133722b4/LekaryusijefowHirgemsterevepalltrallxay)

Comment: 谢谢！Do you know how to show flyout when the text is selected? I have posted another question about that and that is something I want to achieve. So I was thinking maybe I can get answer from this question,  but apparently this is not the solution. Thanks anyway, take a look of my another question if you'd like to. [How to show a flyout in where the text in a TextBlock is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138073/how-to-show-a-flyout-in-where-the-text-in-a-textblock-is-selected)

Comment: Hey, 原来是来自中国的小伙伴，真担心我的英文太渣。